Help writing a python script for Solana smart contract
I have this smart contract and I cant seem to make a python script that would create necessary accounts and demonstrate buy and sell options I would really appreciate any help or link to a YouTube tutorial that would allow me to make that script:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer};

declare_id!("25uXkbJzkM9Cmciy6gYwJ3pVGC9XDQvX64VyWGKHinkj");

#[program]
pub mod token_contract {
    use super::*;

    // Initialize the contract state
    pub fn initialize_contract_state(ctx: Context<InitializeContractState>, owner: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        let contract_state = &mut ctx.accounts.contract_state;
        contract_state.fee_pool = 0;
        contract_state.owner = owner;
        contract_state.last_buy_timestamp = 0;
        contract_state.last_sell_timestamp = 0;
        Ok(())
    }

    // Buy function: Transfers SOL to contract and sends tokens back to user
    pub fn buy(ctx: Context<Buy>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let fee = amount / 100; // 1% fee
        let transfer_amount = amount - fee;

        // Transfer SOL to contract
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.user_token_account.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.contract_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
            },
        );
        token::transfer(cpi_ctx, transfer_amount)?;

        // Save the fee in contract's fee pool
        ctx.accounts.contract_state.fee_pool += fee;
        ctx.accounts.contract_state.last_buy_timestamp = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;

        Ok(())
    }

    // Sell function: Transfers tokens to contract and sends SOL back to user
    pub fn sell(ctx: Context<Sell>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let fee = amount / 100; // 1% fee
        let transfer_amount = amount - fee;

        // Transfer tokens to contract
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.user_token_account.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.contract_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
            },
        );
        token::transfer(cpi_ctx, transfer_amount)?;

        // Save the fee in contract's fee pool
        ctx.accounts.contract_state.fee_pool += fee;
        ctx.accounts.contract_state.last_sell_timestamp = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;

        Ok(())
    }

    // Distribute fees on December 25th
    pub fn distribute_fees(ctx: Context<DistributeFees>) -> Result<()> {
        let contract_state = &mut ctx.accounts.contract_state;
        let current_timestamp = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;

        // Calculate the Unix timestamp for December 25th of the current year (midnight UTC)
        let current_year = (current_timestamp / 31_536_000) + 1970;  // Approximate years from Unix epoch
        let target_timestamp = calculate_december_25_timestamp(current_year);

        // Check if today is December 25th
        if current_timestamp >= target_timestamp {
            let total_fee_pool = contract_state.fee_pool;
            
            // Calculate 5% for the owner
            let owner_share = total_fee_pool / 20; // 5% of the fee pool

            // Calculate the remaining 95% for users
            let user_share = total_fee_pool - owner_share;

            // Transfer the owner's 5% share
            let cpi_ctx_owner = CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.contract_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.contract_token_account.to_account_info(),
                },
            );
            token::transfer(cpi_ctx_owner, owner_share)?;

            // Perform the transfer to users (buyer/seller in this example)
            let cpi_ctx_users = CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.contract_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.user_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.contract_token_account.to_account_info(),
                },
            );

            // Transfer the remaining 95% to users
            token::transfer(cpi_ctx_users, user_share)?;

            // Reset the fee pool after distribution
            contract_state.fee_pool = 0;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

// Function to calculate Unix timestamp for December 25th at midnight (UTC)
fn calculate_december_25_timestamp(year: i64) -> i64 {
    let days_in_year = 365 * (year - 1970) + (year - 1969) / 4; // Approximate days in year
    let days_until_dec_25 = 358; // December 25th is the 359th day of the year, considering leap years
    let seconds_in_a_day = 86400;

    (days_in_year + days_until_dec_25) * seconds_in_a_day
}

// Contract state with fee pool, owner, and timestamps
#[account]
pub struct ContractState {
    pub fee_pool: u64,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub last_buy_timestamp: i64,
    pub last_sell_timestamp: i64,
}

// Struct for initializing contract state
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeContractState<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 32 + 8 + 8 + 8)] // 8 for account discriminator, 32 for Pubkey, 8 for fee_pool, 8 for timestamps
    pub contract_state: Account<'info, ContractState>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>, // User paying for initialization
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>, // System program for account creation
}

// Struct for the buy operation
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Buy<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract_state: Account<'info, ContractState>,
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

// Struct for the sell operation
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Sell<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract_state: Account<'info, ContractState>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

// Struct for the distribute fees operation
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DistributeFees<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract_state: Account<'info, ContractState>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,  // Account where owner's share will be transferred
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}



As of December 2024, Seahorse (the Python project to make Solana programs / smart contracts is no longer maintained.
While there is early support for TypeScript, the most complete framework for building Solana programs is Anchor on Rust.
